# Stop access to directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web

I am trying to stop access to two certain folders with this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(nigel/|multicraft/) - [F,L,NC]
```

I get a `500 Internal Server Error` when I open the website in a browser.

Comment: one easy way put an .htaccess file in that directories and write `deny from all` to .htaccess file

Comment: I am deploying the website with Capistrano and it creates folders each time I deploy so I would have to create the .htaccess every time.

Comment: ok if you want to do it with one .htaccess you should change it everytime and its not good and/or dangerous.

Comment: Look into your apache error log see what error is causing 500.

Answer (score 0):

Put `.htaccess` in the directories with this content:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny From All
```